# Tridion UI - ExperienceManager Startup

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

When clicking on the Tridion UI button, where is the underlying activity logged?

I am getting a few error messages on startup, however, they are not logged in the Tridion windows event log which is where I was expecting them.

One of the errors is for instance:

> ERROR:  The requested service,
>   'http://localhost/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetSiteEditItemConfiguration'
>   could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information.

Another:

> ERROR:
>   /WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetBluePrintContextItemsIds
>   failed to execute. STATUS (500):
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException

Thanks a lot

Comment: First thing to try is to restart IIS, but I guess you already did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed by re-installing Experience Manager.

Comment: Hi Elena - I know this is a post from long back. We are facing it too.. I see in firebug that the first tcmid on this ajax call is a blank string. And I sense thats the possible cause. Do you know of a better or possible solution instead?

Answer (score 5):

It can be several things, but when I get this error is because there's a problem with the service being called, i.e.:`/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc` , and the main cause has always been that there's not enough memory in the server.

You can also check the Event Viewer within `Event Viewer/ Windows Logs/Application`. There you should see the actual cause of the error with a more detailed Stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

500 (Internal Server) errors are usually logged in the Application log of Event Viewer, as *warnings* from ASP.NET.

You can also try opening the failing URL directly in your browser, as that can sometimes reveal configuration issues (your "could not be activated" error is a good candidate for that)